# confusion for view's and viewmodel's responsibility in mvvm architecture in android

Tags: architecture, android, mvvm

i have a confusion about what code should be placed in view and what in viewmodel

for example click events

here is a snippet code of google ToDo app example for showing application architecture ([Link](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/usecases/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.kt)):

```
//this code is placed in view (TasksFragment)
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) =
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_clear -> {
                viewModel.clearCompletedTasks()
                true
            }
            R.id.menu_filter -> {
                showFilteringPopUpMenu()
                true
            }
            R.id.menu_refresh -> {
                viewModel.loadTasks(true)
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }

private fun showFilteringPopUpMenu() {
    val view = activity?.findViewById<View>(R.id.menu_filter) ?: return
    PopupMenu(requireContext(), view).run {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.filter_tasks, menu)

        setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            viewModel.setFiltering(
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.active -> TasksFilterType.ACTIVE_TASKS
                    R.id.completed -> TasksFilterType.COMPLETED_TASKS
                    else -> TasksFilterType.ALL_TASKS
                }
            )
            viewModel.loadTasks(false)
            true
        }
        show()
    }
}
```

as you can see there are 3 three items for a menu

2 of them delegated to viewmodel and one handled in view

beside that there are some logic in view that make decision based on view's id, but in mvvm definition said there must be no condition in view

Comment: It isn't using a condition, it is setting a filter. The distinction is important.

Comment: @BobDalgleish but what about the task that delegate them to viewmodel and other that handle it itself?

Comment: MVVM has fundamental difficulties with scaling and scope of responsibilities. You will run into similar issues.